# Triggering of Twilio.Device.offline due to the expiry of Capability Token

Tags: twilio

I want to generate a new Capability Token whenever the existing Token expires using Twilio.Device's offline handler.But this is triggered even when the connection is dropped.
   Is there any way to know whether the Twilio.Device.offline(handler()) is triggered due to the expiry of Capability Token alone.

Comment: Please share your code/workaround so that others can take a look.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#example-code                       See also                              https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think there's a way to only trigger `Twilio.Device.offline(handler())` when a token expires, you can ensure token expiry by checking for [Error 31205](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors) `JWT Token Expired`.

Upon log of this error you can then handle it in your application as you see fit.